# Adding product condition to orderid API in BigCommerce

Tags: netsuite, bigcommerce

I am pulling data from BigCommerce and putting it into NetSuite.  I am pulling data from the productAPI in big commerce.  I am pulling from products.json and i see this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "order_id":15683,
      "product_id":3854,
      "order_address_id":1,
      "name":"Cisco 1000BASE-SX SFP Transceiver Module GLC-SX-MM=",
      "sku":"GLC-SX-MM",
      "type":"physical",
      "base_price":"39.9500",
      "price_ex_tax":"39.9500",
      "price_inc_tax":"39.9500",
      "price_tax":"0.0000",
      "base_total":"39.9500",
      "total_ex_tax":"39.9500",
      "total_inc_tax":"39.9500",
      "total_tax":"0.0000",
      "weight":"4.4000",
      "quantity":1,
      "base_cost_price":"0.0000",
      "cost_price_inc_tax":"0.0000",
      "cost_price_ex_tax":"0.0000",
      "cost_price_tax":"0.0000",
      "is_refunded":false,
      "refund_amount":"0.0000",
      "return_id":0,
      "wrapping_name":"",
      "base_wrapping_cost":"0.0000",
      "wrapping_cost_ex_tax":"0.0000",
      "wrapping_cost_inc_tax":"0.0000",
      "wrapping_cost_tax":"0.0000",
      "wrapping_message":"",
      "quantity_shipped":0,
      "event_name":null,
      "event_date":"",
      "fixed_shipping_cost":"0.0000",
      "ebay_item_id":"",
      "ebay_transaction_id":"",
      "option_set_id":null,
      "parent_order_product_id":null,
      "is_bundled_product ":false,
      "bin_picking_number":"",
      "applied_discounts":[  

      ],
      "product_options":[  

      ],
      "configurable_fields":[  

      ]
   }
]
```

the problem is that my netsuite requires a field that is in bigcommerce, but not in this dataset.  is there a way to enable a specific field(prodcondition) to be a part of this dataset?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question to make the JSON more readable by using some indentation? You can also put it in a code block - mark the text and push the {} button.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little more to have us a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The problem i am having is that i am pulling data through the product details api as i am passing an order from BC to NS.  Our NS configuration requires a 'product condition'  the problem is that that field is not in the specific api where i am pulling data.  i believe it is in a product details api, which i do not want to pull.  basically, the order can be pulled at a order level but we are checking at an item level.  So, what i am looking for is a solution to be able to pass all order details plus the data from this one single field.

Answer (score 1):

Product condition isn't available through a request to the orders resource, only through the aforementioned product resource.

There are a few third party apps/integrations with Bigcommerce that do bridge Netsuite to BC, but I believe they've done so by grabbing the product ID from order details to query the product resource for the condition of the item before passing the order info into Netsuite.